# How do I show map in UML? C++

Tags: c++, uml, associative-array

I have a "Database" class that has a template "myMap" that stores instances of the "Client" class. The "myMap" consists of nodes (instances of the "Node" class). How do I show this in UML?

```
template<typename KEY, typename VALUE> class myMap;

template <typename KEY, typename VALUE>
class Node
{
private:
    friend class myMap<KEY, VALUE>;
    KEY id;
    VALUE object;
    Node* parent;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};

template<typename KEY, typename VALUE>
class myMap
{
    Node<KEY, VALUE>* root;
    ////
};

class Client
{
    int id;
};

class Database
{
    myMap<int, Client> clients;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A map between type `K` and type `V`, noted  in C++ with `std::map<K,V>` is typically modelled in UML using an [association with a qualifier](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/property.html#qualifier), the qualifier being of type `:K` and the other end of the association being of type `V`.

The qualifier is used in conjunction with a source type `T` that is at the first end of the association. In C++, this means that the map would be a member of `T`. In your case it would be `Database`.

Comment: Like this?
https://pastenow.ru/1188ad5441fb8e1d793d70ebdb54e4e5

Comment: @insania37 yes! That’s it